# Determine size of struct cast to char*

Tags: c++

```
Packets::LoginData data;
data.username = "frostraver";
data.password = "test";

auto buffer = reinterpret_cast<char*>(&data);
```

I have the code above. I need to be able to calculate the size of the data in the buffer (which is a pointer). I know I can't just do a strlen or something similar.

What's the best way to get the size of this? Can I just take the size of the filled in struct?

Comment: You'd better calculate the lengths for each one of those char arrays, a sizeof(data) won't work

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem - what are you really trying to do?

Comment: Why are you doing this? Serialize the data in a sane way.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath: because `sizeof(Packets::LoginData) == 2*sizeof(char*)` assuming the two fields are `char*`.

Comment: @larsm: yes. but that assumes this is for serialization, which case the whole cast thing doesn't make sense...

Comment: @OP Post a full sample please! [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @KarolyHorvath There are a lot of sites that suggest doing `reinterpret_cast<char *>(&some_object)` and writing out `sizeof(some_object)` characters from the resulting pointer as a way to serialize objects, which only works for objects that contain no pointers, no virtual methods, nor any types (recursively) that do either. This means `std::string` is out for example, since it contains a pointer to a heap allocation. It's a very fragile technique and people try to use it every day without any regard for all of the really bad things that can happen.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath Oh and that will break too if the serialized object is read back in on a machine with different endianness, or more generally where any of the types have a different layout than they did on the machine where it was serialized. (This could happen with any primitive type where the size isn't guaranteed by the standard, such as `int`, which can vary between compilers.)

Comment: @cdhowie: obviously.

Answer (score 1):

No it is not possible. `buffer` which is of type `Packets::LoginData*` is just a pointer variable without any size information. Even if you would determine the Size of the structure , that may not be complete as because one or more of your fields may in-turn be a pointer leading to invalid/incorrect/incomplete result.

The following figure summarizes the answer

```
                         Packets::LoginData
                         ____________________
                        |                    |        __________________ 
                        | username (char *)--|------>|_|_|_|_|_|_|..._|_| (username)
                        |                    |        __________________
buffer----------------->| password (char *)--|------>|_|_|_|_|_|_|..._|_| (password )
                        |                    |
                        | ..............     |
                        |____________________|
```

Most importantly, C++ doesn't support reflection, so a general solution for serialzation without explicit support is meaningless

Comment: you could recommend std::string if he despretly needs the size

Comment: @Creris But `std::string` stores its value on the heap; it contains a `char*` too, and so would be no better.

Comment: @cdhowie I dont think it matters if it is stored in heap or not. Yes it also contains char*, but at least it is aware of its size

Comment: @Creris: Most importantly, C++ doesn't support reflection, so a general solution for serialzation without explicit support is meaningless

Comment: @Creris It does matter. If you are using this method to serialize an object you'll just get a pointer to the string contents, which will be invalid when it is read back in later. Or -- even worse -- you would wind up with two string objects thinking they own the same allocation.